# Where is my Pokemon X rival supposed to be?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Where is your rival supposed to be at in Kiloude city? I can't seem to find her. I have battled A LOT in the Battle Mansion and already have 187 BP.

Answer (score 4):

Your rival awaits you each day up the stairs around the Battle Mansion, all the way up to the top, near the pond.

Comment: Letting the poor girl wait for days... that's pretty cruel ;)

Comment: @Nolonar Especially in the rain!